# Rails: Elegant way to push parts of the association into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, model, associations

I've got a `post` and an `author` model.

`author has_many :posts`

Now I have an `author` with several `posts`

Is there an elegant way to get only the `posts'` `titles` as an array, not the whole `post` object?

So, not just `author.posts` but something like `author.posts.only(:title)` to get an array of titles. E.g. `['post1','post2','post3']`.

That `.only(:title)` syntax is from the JSON module and doesn't work in this case but there might be something more elegant than iterating over the `posts` and pushing the `titles` into a new array. Something that queries the DB like `select titles from posts where author_id = 23`.

?

Answer (score 5):

Use `pluck`

```
author.posts.pluck(:title)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck

> pluck(column_name)
>
> This method is designed to perform select by a
>   single column as direct SQL query Returns Array with values of the
>   specified column name The values has same data type as column.